# The null character at the end of string literal

Tags: c, string-literals

I wrote two versions of codes to practice how to make a character array, and I was expecting the result to be the same.

version 1:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[7] = "and";

    printf("size: %d   length: %d",sizeof(a), strlen(a) );
}
```

version 2:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[7];
    a[1] = 'a';
    a[2] = 'n';
    a[3] = 'd';

    printf("size: %d   length: %d",sizeof(a), strlen(a) );
}
```

However, here is the result I got:

version 1:

```
size: 7   length: 3
```

version 2:

```
size: 7   length: 4
```

As far as I know, the string ends with null character, and null character in a string literal is implicit, but why did it disappear? Why didn't it be included as the last element as length in Version 1 shows 3?

Comment: `char a[7];`: do not assume that an uninitialized array contains zeroes.

Comment: In your second code block, you're neither assigning from a string literal, nor are you writing to the start of your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact `strlen` is supposed to exclude the null character, so the output `3` is correct. The problem with the second version is that a[7] is not initialized so its values may be arbitrary. It just so happens in this case that the 5th value is 0 and the 0th is not, thus the output 4. Note that in the second version you use wrong indices - indexing of arrays starts from 0, not from 1.

If you want to make this work in the second version, re-write it like so:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[7] = {0};
    a[0] = 'a';
    a[1] = 'n';
    a[2] = 'd';

    printf("size: %d   length: %d",sizeof(a), strlen(a) );
}
```

This initializes the first value in a to 0 explicitly and implicitly makes all other values zero too.

Comment: Note you copied a mistake from the question: not starting at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` measure the memory size of something. `strlen` calculates the length of a c-string (length defined as the length of the sequence of characters excluding the nul terminating one). Here your c-string is shorter than the memory used to store it.

`sizeof` is C-operator evaluated as compile-time.

`strlen` is a library function, called at runtime.

> `strlen(3)`
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>   The strlen() function computes the length of the string s.
>
> **RETURN VALUES**
>   The strlen() function returns the number of characters that precede the
>        terminating NUL character.

Beware that your second example is undefined as the character array is not initialized, `strlen` may overflow... You have no guarantee that non initialized chars are set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

As per [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) description:

> ```
> size_t strlen(const char *str);
> ```
>
> Returns the length of the given null-terminated byte string, that is, the number of characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by `str` up to and not including the first null character.
>   The behavior is undefined if `str` is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string.

Since in the second version, `a` is not a null-terminated byte string, the [behavior is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Note that assigning individual character literals to a `char` array does not make it a string literal, to create a properly null-terminated `char` array using that kind of assignment you need to do it yourself, starting at index `0`:

```
a[0] = 'a';
//...
a[3] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[7];
    a[1] = 'a';
    a[2] = 'n';
    a[3] = 'd';

    printf("size: %d   length: %d",sizeof(a), strlen(a) );
}
```

you are lucky that

- `a[0]` did not contain a `0` (i.e, `'\0'` or null) : you would have seen a value `0` as length.
- `a[4]` actually had a null value, otherwise, your computer might have been burnt!!

In other words, for a local variable with automatic storage, if left uninitialized, the values are indeterminate. There's no guarantee of a 0-filling (which acts as null terminator), so using the array as a string (ex: argument to `strlen()`) will likely have an effect of accessing out of bound memory and  invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).